# How to create M365 dynamic groups from CSV file using powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, csv, active-directory, azure-active-directory

I've been tasked with creating 1600 O365 dynamic groups for our Azure AD deployment. We currently have all the syntax/group rules created for these groups in a CSV file. My problem is: i'm using the following script to try to create these groups

```
Connect-AzureAD
$Groups = Import-Csv -Path C:\Temp\AzureAD_Groups.csv
$dynamicGroupTypeString = "DynamicMembership"

foreach($Group in $Groups)
{
New-AzureADGroup -DisplayName $Group.DisplayName -Description $Group.Description -MailEnabled $False -MailNickName "group" -SecurityEnabled $True -membershipRule $Group.MembershipRule -GroupTypes $dynamicGroupTypeString
}
```

After running this script i get the error:

```
New-AzureADGroup : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'membershipRule'.
At line:8 char:147
+ ...  -MailNickName "group" -SecurityEnabled $True -membershipRule $Group. ...
```

I looked into this error and i see that this flag/parameter doesnt exist for New-AzureADGroup and i also saw that it works for Set-AzureADGroup. My question is: instead of creating then setting the group rules after, can i perform this task all in one script so it creates the groups then uses the pre-made syntax in my CSV?

My CSV file is setup as such:
[image]

Any help is much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got the same error like below:***

[image]

My Imported **CSV file** looks like below:

[image]

> Please note that, you have to use **New-AzureADMSGroup** command to create M365 Dynamic group. Make sure to include **`-MembershipRuleProcessingState`** **"On"** while using that command.

***I'm able to create dynamic groups successfully after changing the script like below:***

```
Connect-AzureAD
$Groups = Import-Csv -Path "C:\test\AzureAD_groups.csv"
$dynamicGroupTypeString = "DynamicMembership"

foreach($Group in $Groups)
{
New-AzureADMSGroup -DisplayName $Group.DisplayName -Description $Group.Description -MailEnabled $False -MailNickName "group" -SecurityEnabled $True -membershipRule $Group.MembershipRule -GroupTypes $dynamicGroupTypeString -MembershipRuleProcessingState "On"
}
```

[image]

***M365 dynamic groups created successfully like below:***

[image]

***Members are dynamically allotted to groups based on membership rules like below:***

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is great! Thank you SrideviMachavarapu! Is there a way to silence the welcome message/notification for new users that are dynamically added to the group? I see this parameter: [-UnifiedGroupWelcomeMessageEnabled]
Is there a way to run this inline so it silences all new notifications?
Would it be after "-MembershipRuleProcessingState "On" -UnifiedGroupWelcomeMessageEnabled "false""

Thank you!